# Discord.py Get a username by the user id in the console without a discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Heyy, my question is if i can get the `username` by the `user id`.
For example to use such an id `'54233616**********'` to get the `username` and or the `usertag`.

Comment: Note this requires a bot, as dpy uses the bot api to do this. This can be done with a self bot, but that is against Discord ToS and cannot be condoned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do! You can simply use `bot.fetch_user`, to fetch the user's information

```
async def get_user_by_id(id):
    user = await bot.fetch_user(id)
    print(user.name)
```

Have a nice day :)